# Gravitational potential in an expanding universe during the matter era

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

In the book *Cosmology*, by Daniel Baumann, there is an exercise to show, using the Poisson equation, that the gravitational potential is a constant during the matter era. As I understand, the Poisson equation in an expanding Universe for the background gravitational potential is
$$ \nabla^2 \bar{\Phi} = 4\pi G a^2 \bar{\rho} \ ,$$
where $a$ is the scale factor.
But, in the matter era, we have $\bar{\rho} \propto a^{-3}$, which would give $\nabla^2 \bar{\Phi} \propto a^{-1}$ and the gravitational potential wouldn't be a constant. Can anyone help me figure out where is my reasoning wrong?

Should I focus on the gravitational potential perturbations instead?